# ActiveMQ feature similar to MassTransit Saga

Tags: activemq-classic, masstransit, saga

Is there any alternative to MassTransit Saga feature in ActiveMQ?
As a student, I've learned MassTransit and now I want to learn ActiveMQ by analogy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ is a message broker. Not a long running, transactional state machine.